# How close are we to making a wormhole?

Tags: wormholes

Is humanity nearing the ability to construct a stable wormhole?

It's been something that was depicted for a while in various science-fiction shows; but are we getting close?

Do quantum computers factor into this entire thing?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-05424-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wormholes are theoretical solutions to the equations of General Relativity. It is not clear that they correspond to physically realisable objects, and they lead to problems with causality that should make us suspicious of viewing them as more than abstract curiosities. Even if that were not the case, wormholes are generally considered to be non-traversible, in the sense that they would likely disassociate macroscopic objects into their constituent particles.

Extensions to quantum mechanical situations make them more speculative, not less, as we lack a working theory of quantum gravity.

As always there may be some technical issue of which I am ignorant that changes the situation, but in that case I will leave it to someone more knowledgeable to make the case.